# How to make a address to string

Tags: string-manipulation, syntax, customization

I get a *Window address*,Of course it should be a string in generally,but I got a non-string by some method,such as paste your clipboard into your *notebook* directly or other ways.I want to do some string-manipulation in following step,so I try to convert it into a string.But as we know this expression will give error information

```
ToString[C:\Users\Default]
```

Because the `ToString` will be at loss in how to deal with the escape character, but can we implement this in `Mathematica`?

Answer (score 4):

To avoid any syntax errors you need to use `$PreRead` (tutorial/WolframSystemSessions), which is already a limiting factor. Nevertheless:

```
$PreRead = # /. RowBox[
   {h_, ":", RowBox[p : {PatternSequence["\\", _] .., "\\" ...}]}
] :> StringJoin@Flatten[{"\"", h, ":", p /. "\\" -> "\\\\", "\""}] &
```

[image]

Comment: Little hacky...

Comment: @yode you want to interprete completely wrong syntax, what did you expect?

Comment: After some caculation,I get that which is a *Window address*.I should do some string manipulation,so I should convert it to string firstly.And actually I expected another method not use `$PreRead`.

Comment: @yode, how does the address get into *Mathematica* in the first place? Is it typed in by a user, is it the output of some script, or what?

Comment: @J.M. it is a output of a expression.

Comment: @yode, which expression? In *Mathematica*, or in another external program?

Comment: @J.M. Yes,from a *C#* program,but that is important to this post?

Comment: But @yode, if you're [running this external program from within *Mathematica*](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/ExternalPrograms.html), I don't understand why the output would not be a string... if you're importing the output of the program (a text file?) into *Mathematica*, the situation in your OP shouldn't occur either.

Comment: @J.M. I have read your link,confusing me too,but if my bad code lead me to get that stuff really.Can we interprete that into string?

Comment: What is important to know is how that got into your mathematica session. Did you paste it, type it, `Import` , what?

Answer (score 2):

You can tell *Mathematica* that it is a string and to escape the required characters by simply pasting it between two double quotes , `""`.

With `C:\Users\Default` copied to the clipboard, enter two double quotes and paste between them.  You should be prompted with the following.

[image]

Select *Yes* and the result in the notebook is as required.

```
"C:\\Users\\Default"
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This is current method,but I hope use code method.Can we implement it?